# Routing resolve does not work if resource returns error code 400

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, resolve

In my app.js i have:

```
 resolve : {
                    resetCodeCheckData : function(resource) {
                            return resource.get().$promise;
                    }
        }
```

But if the result of the resource has 400 header set then the control does not even pass to the controller. The execution ends right after ajax call response is received. How do Ii resolve this?

Comment: afaik you can't it's the wanted behaviour btw it should be resetCodeCheckData : function(resource) {
                            return resource.get().$promise;
                    }

Comment: editted the code. Thanks. But why is it unwanted behaviour? If i call the same resource in the controller with the header recieving 400 error, it works fine.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider I don't really know why the angular folks went to this point but all in all it seems a good point imo if the request call fails do nothing

Comment: but y do nothing only when resolving and not when in the controller?

Comment: the promise fails do nothing means not to pass to an other router read the link I've posted before

Comment: i read .. its d general descrption please post the part u r referring to

Answer (score 0):

$resource returns a promise by default. If the resolve fails the 'resetCodeCheckData' in the controller would be an error message or any custom message you set in the resource service.

```
resolve: {
    resetCodeCheckData: ['SomeResourceService',function(SomeResourceService){
      return SomeResourceService.get();
      // return SomeResourceService.query();
    }];
}
```

Comment: i tried this. still the flow doesnt pass on to the controller

Comment: @BhumiSinghal add a plunkr or jsfiddle with more code to take a closer look.

Comment: Adding a plunkr wont help as i will need to call my web scripts from there which i will want to avoid